# bisect plane normal (mesh and bmesh) how calc the 3th vector to mathutils.geometry?

Tags: python, scripting, mesh, bmesh, mathematics

**UPDATE 1:  how calc the 3th vector to mathutils.geometry.normal(vectors)??**

After @Chebhou answer I tried my "bisector tool" again... with mesh and bmesh.. now the problem is the 3th vector to calc the plane_normal in `mathutils.geometry.normal(vectors)`

I think that 3th vector should be align to view..... then I tried with camera and or cursor location with this results:

inicial state is:  [download .blend please](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4230273/D_O/text%20cut.blend)

[image: inicial state]

**the first try** with"pure" bisect tool give this data... this is correct then I need reproduce this same data with my addon:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(plane_co=(1.57825, 1.50332, -0.165924), plane_no=(0.695399, -0.691791, 0.194541), xstart=167, xend=628, ystart=443, yend=422)
```

and this result:

[image: bisect tool]

**second try** is with bpy.ops.mesh.bisect that give me this data:

in this case vectors are vertice 1 and vertice 2 selected and the camera location

as you see the cut is good but the location (I think the plane_co) is wrong!

```
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(plane_co=(1.36157, 1.69042, 0.804025), plane_no=(-0.660225, 0.660225, -0.358059), use_fill=False, clear_inner=False, clear_outer=False, threshold=0.0001, xstart=404, xend=770, ystart=468, yend=450, cursor=1002)
```

[image: bisect addon 1]

**last try** give me this data:

[image: bmesh data]

as you see , plane_co is correct but the plane_no is incorrect!

[image: bmesh bisect result]

**how calc the 3th vector to mathutils.geometry.normal(vectors)??**

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Actually I have a problem with the bisect tool...

this is from mesh:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(
   plane_co=plane_co,
   plane_no=plane_no, 
   use_fill=False, clear_inner=False, 
   clear_outer=False, threshold=0.0001, 
   xstart=0, 
   xend=0, 
   ystart=0, 
   yend=0, 
   cursor=1002)
```

and this from bmesh:

```
bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(
            bm,
            geom=visible_geom,
            dist=dist,
            plane_co=plane_co, 
            plane_no=plane_no,
            use_snap_center=False,
            clear_outer=False,
            clear_inner=False)
```

after a lot of effort I thought that  I found the plane_normal equation..... for example for  bmesh:

```
         v1,v2 = [v.co for v in bm.verts if (v.select == True and v.hide == False)]


        # plane_no math:

        normal = ((v1.y*v2.z)-(v1.z*v2.y)), ((v1.z*v2.x)-(v1.x*v2.z)),((v1.x*v2.y)-(v1.y*v2.x))
        print("thenormal " + str(normal))


        plane_no = normal
        plane_co = v2
```

but NO!!!

Actually I know that `xstart=0, xend=0, ystart=0, yend=0,` are the initial and final location of Operative System Cursor (not 3d blender cursor).. and this data help to  blender in order to calc the plane_co

anyway... I can calc the plane_co because it is any point in the cut plane... but actually I don't know how to calc the plane_normal....

thanks for any help

Comment: see if this is the behavior you are after, if it is i'll update my answer to explain more  [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/143/)

Comment: @Chebhou thanks for help.... in order to be honest is really difficult to know if your example is what I want....   in a fast reply I think yes... but I'm not sure. thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plane normal is the Cross Product of two vectors laying on that plane

> N = normalize( Vect(P1,P2) X Vect(P1, P3) )

where Pn is point on the plane 
all these calculation are done using the `mathutils.geometry.normal(vectors)` which takes 3 points and return the normal vector

***Note:*** Normal direction depends on the Points order

---

**Update**

to get the third Point we use the function `region_2d_to_vector_3d()` which take a 2d coordinates and returns the a normalized vector of the view at this point ,then we add this vector to the point which we used its 2d coordinates to get a new one on the same line of sight (same plane ) , at last we pass the three points to the `normal()`

```
v3 =  view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(viewport, area.spaces[0].region_3d, co_2d)
v3 = v3+ vert[1].co

normal =  mathutils.geometry.normal(vert[0].co,vert[1].co,v3)
```

**Note** you have to pass the the `co_2d` not `co_2d_w` to the `bisect()`

the file [image]

Comment: actually I have a problem with the 3th vector.... I update the post in order to give more information... thanks againg for any data or example

Comment: Thanks for amazing answer... fast question.. why you add v1.co to v3?? 

 v3 = v3+ vert[1].co

Comment: you can do that to vert[0], the idea is to get a point behind this vert on the same plane ( camera--->vert------->new_Ponit ), you can substract but it will be the same